# Loop Through excel file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm a beginner in Powershell, and I have a code that loop through PDF files get all their names.
Then loop in an excel file for a match if true give the name of the site. here is a sample of my [PDF Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chRfv.png),  [Excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ifu5.png) and Code explained, if you need any other explanation please tell me :

## I get all Files Name here

```
$filename = Get-childItem "T:\DVO\DVO-S\Activites\Gestion - Information clients\Base Installee\02-LOGISTIQUE\SB - TU\SB NORIA\FAIT BI\*" -Recurse  | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer}
```

## Set the root to the Excel File and Workbook sheet

```
$fil = '\\tm.corp\turbomeca\DVO\D2S-MRO\Activites\30-Noria\30-01 Activité\30-01-04 Plan de Progrès\2020-PDP\Fiches projet\44- simplification traitement des CoC Noria\extract pour projet gestion des CoC\Noria - Noria Search Advanced.xlsx'
$sheetName = "Noria - Noria Search Advanced"
```

## Open the File

```
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($fil)
$sheet = $WorkBook.worksheets.Item($sheetName)
 $objExcel.visible = $false
 $objExcel.DisplayAlerts = $false
```

## Set the last Row

```
$rowMax = ($Sheet.usedRange.rows).count
```

## Select the columns I want to work with

```
$RowNoria, $colNoria = 4,1 #Noria column
$RowNheSN,$colNheSN = 4,6 # NHESN column
$RowSite, $colSite =  4,29 #Site column
```

Here I want To get for every file the SN which is the bold part on this exemple of file name
$SN = **10074**_292720384_C_2021.05.07.pdf (every thing before the first "underscore")
and then get the SB number which is
$SB = 10074_292720**384**_C_2021.05.07.pdf (3 last numbers of the number between "underscore"
I then tried to put the $SB in a way that can match the names in Noria column by doing this  `$SBF = "*_*$SB_*"`

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $filename.Count; $i++){
       $F = $filename[$i].Name
       $F
       $SN = $F.split("_")[0]
       $split = $F.split("_")[1] 
       $SB = -join $split[-3..-1]
       $SBF = "*_*$SB_*"
```

In this loop I added a loop that is going to look for $SN in NHESN column and try to find that exact number and look for $SBF in the Noria column. If this two condition are met give me the SITE in the same Row

```
for($j=1; $j -le $rowMax-1; $j++){
        $Noria = $sheet.cells.Item($RowNoria+$j, $colNoria).text
        $NheSN = $sheet.cells.Item($RowNheSN+$j, $colNheSN).text
        $Site = $sheet.cells.Item($RowSite+$j, $colSite).text
        if ($Noria -like $SBF -and $NheSN -eq $SN) {
        
                Write-Host ($Noria)
                Write-Host ($Site)
                write-Host ($NheSN)
                Break
                }
        else {Continue}
      }
```

As a Result I need This For exemple

- If File name : *10074*_292720**384**_C_2021.05.07.pdf
- Noria : ARL1_SB0**384**_MO3_T2 1D-1D1
- Site : TSF
- NHESN : *10074*

and once i get it go to next file

But The result I get is Once it found a match in SN ($SN -eq $NHESN) it gave me the first row with that SN or NHESN but I want the row with the two condition for $SN -eq $NHESN and $SBF -eq $NORIA to be true
The false result i get for exemple is

- If File name : *10074*_292720**384**_C_2021.05.07.pdf
- Noria : ARL1_SB0**786**_MO3_T2 1D-1D1
- Site : TSF
- NHESN : *10074*

Thank you in advance for your time and help

And here is the all the code

```
$filename = Get-childItem "T:\DVO\DVO-S\Activites\Gestion - Information clients\Base Installee\02-LOGISTIQUE\SB - TU\SB NORIA\FAIT BI\*" -Recurse  | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer}

$fil = '\\tm.corp\turbomeca\DVO\D2S-MRO\Activites\30-Noria\30-01 Activité\30-01-04 Plan de Progrès\2020-PDP\Fiches projet\44- simplification traitement des CoC Noria\extract pour projet gestion des CoC\Noria - Noria Search Advanced.xlsx'
$sheetName = "Noria - Noria Search Advanced"

$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($fil)
$sheet = $WorkBook.worksheets.Item($sheetName)
 $objExcel.visible = $false
 $objExcel.DisplayAlerts = $false

$rowMax = ($Sheet.usedRange.rows).count

$RowNoria, $colNoria = 4,1
$RowNheSN,$colNheSN = 4,6
$RowSite, $colSite =  4,29

for ($i=0; $i -lt $filename.Count; $i++){


       $F = $filename[$i].Name
       $F
       $SN = $F.split("_")[0]
       $split = $F.split("_")[1] 
       $SB = -join $split[-3..-1]
       $SBF = "*_*$SB_*"
                         
    for($j=1; $j -le $rowMax-1; $j++){
        $Noria = $sheet.cells.Item($RowNoria+$j, $colNoria).text
        $NheSN = $sheet.cells.Item($RowNheSN+$j, $colNheSN).text
        $Site = $sheet.cells.Item($RowSite+$j, $colSite).text
        if ($Noria -like $SBF -and $NheSN -eq $SN) {
        
                Write-Host ($Noria)
                Write-Host ($Site)
                write-Host ($NheSN)
                Break
                }
        else {Continue}
      }
             
    }
$objExcel.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_` is a valid character for variable names, so $SBF is getting set incorrectly on this line:

```
$SBF = "*_*$SB_*"
```

Use a backtick to escape it:

```
$SBF = "*_*$SB`_*"
```