# How to ADD a file to a variable Powershell

Tags: powershell

In addition to what I did here:

[Loop Through excel file using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68677704/loop-through-excel-file-using-powershell)

I want to send a mail with only the files that are transfered, and I got a small problem with that. To do that and foreach file transfered I added the file to a variable `$FilenameFR` with the script below.

Here is what I tried

```
#Look for each number in the columns selected    
    for($j=1; $j -le $rowMax-1; $j++){
        
        $Noria = $sheet.cells.Item($RowNoria+$j, $colNoria).text
        $NheSN = $sheet.cells.Item($RowNheSN+$j, $colNheSN).text
        $Site = $sheet.cells.Item($RowSite+$j, $colSite).text
            if ($Noria -like $SBF -and $NheSN -eq $SN) {  
                Write-Host ($Noria)
                Write-Host ($Site)
                write-Host ($NheSN)
                
                If ($Site -eq "TMF" -or $Site -eq "TSF") {
                        Copy-item "P:\MK_M\$F" -Destination "\\inshare.collab.group.safran\COM\NoriaC\CoC\Test_MK_D\France\"
                        $FR = $FR + 1 #coutn how many files I transfered
                        $FilenameFR += $F #here for every file transfered i add it's name to this variable
```

But when I call `$FilenameFR` in my mails with this script

```
$Mail.Body = 
"Hello,

You've received $FR files, if you Could please treat the certificates received on your folder in the next few days it would be very good.

Please find the link to the folder below :

....

Thank you for your understanding and have a nice day.

PS. The files are :
"
         foreach ($File in $FilenameFR) {     # Cette boucle c'est pour avoir un nom de Fichier par ligne dans le mail
         $Mail.Body += "$File"
         }
        $Mail.Send()   
       }
```

Instead of getting each file in line a got them one attached to the other.

exemple : File1.pdfFile2.pdfFile3.pdf ...

Can you please help me with that.

If their is anything not clear please tell me and thank you so much for your help

Comment: Change `+= "$file"` to ``+= "${file}`n"``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your variable `$F` has the filename for each iteration and variable `$FR` is set to zero before the major loop, you do not want to add the filenames with `+=` to an (up to then) undefined variable.
Instead, **capture** the filenames as string array and join these later with newlines in the email.

```
$FR          = 0  # initialize the counter to 0
$source      = 'P:\MK_M'
$destination = '\\inshare.collab.group.safran\COM\NoriaC\CoC\Test_MK_D\France'

# loop through the files
$FilenameFR = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $filename.Count; $i++) {
    $F     = $filename[$i].Name
    $SN    = $F.split("_")[0]
    $split = $F.split("_")[1]
    $SB    = -join $split[-3..-1]
    $SBF   = "*_*$SB`_*"

    # Look for each number in the columns selected    
    for ($j = 1; $j -le $rowMax-1; $j++) {    
        $Noria = $sheet.cells.Item($RowNoria + $j, $colNoria).text
        $NheSN = $sheet.cells.Item($RowNheSN + $j, $colNheSN).text
        $Site  = $sheet.cells.Item($RowSite  +$j, $colSite).text
        if ($Noria -like $SBF -and $NheSN -eq $SN) {  
            Write-Host "$Noria`r`n$Site`r`n$NheSN"
            if ($Site -eq "TMF" -or $Site -eq "TSF") {
                Copy-Item -Path (Join-Path -Path $source -ChildPath $F) -Destination $destination
                # output the filename so it gets collected in variable $FilenameFR
                $F
                $FR++   # increment the file counter
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You now have an **array** of filenames in variable `$FilenameFR` and to use that in the mail body you can do:

```
$Mail.Body = "@
Hello,

You've received $FR files, if you Could please treat the certificates received on your folder in the next few days it would be very good.

Please find the link to the folder below :

....

Thank you for your understanding and have a nice day.

PS. The files are :

%%TRANSFERREDFILES%%
@" -replace '%%TRANSFERREDFILES%%', ($FilenameFR -join [environment]::NewLine)

$Mail.Send()
```

Of course, if this mail is to be sent in HTML format, you need to join the filenames witn `<br />` instead of `[environment]::NewLine`:

```
-replace '%%TRANSFERREDFILES%%', ($FilenameFR -join '<br />')
```

Comment: Thank you as well @Theo you did not only give me an answer to my question but you helped me with all my script, Thank you again !!